# Convert date format (Y-m-d) while importing csv file in database using php

Tags: php, mysql, database, csv

I am working on import the csv file into the database using php.

For that I written php code like below.

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "db_user", "db_password", "db_name");
$sqlInsert = "INSERT into table_name (first_name,last_name,email_address,join_date) values ('" . $column[0] . "','" . $column[1] . "','" . $column[2] . "','" . $column[3] . "')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlInsert);
?>
```

Now I am having csv file with the following date formates (example:(%d-%m-%y) and (%d/%m/%y) ).

**Note:** I have set the date column in "DATE" data type in database.

So in the csv file having both the format, we need to convert it to one format while importing.

How can I convert it to default format like "(Y-m-d)" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Comment: Btw, the default format for MySQL's Date type is `Y-m-d` and for DateTime, it's `Y-m-d H:i:s`.

Comment: It's okay with the "Y-m-d" format. How to convert these to type of format into "Y-m-d". Any idea?

Comment: Did you read the link in my first comment?

Comment: Try this, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-program-change-date-format/

Comment: You can use `LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/file_name.csv' INTO TABLE table_name;`

Comment: Thanks For all your suggestions.

Comment: My issue is while importing csv file "2/18/2019" date is taken as a "0000-00-00" in database. How can we change this format?

Comment: Stop asking “how can I” over and over again, and go read up on this using the resources you have been pointed to!

Answer (score 0):

- try this date_format($date,"Y/m/d H:i:s");
  or
  date_format($date,"Y/m/d");

Comment: Okay Some date like "2011/05/22" and "2011-05-22". How can we convert these to "2011-05-22"